# Calling js String.endsWith / String.slice without parentheses

Tags: javascript, function, parentheses

Lately I saw following code in a project I started working with:

```
if (!filepath || !filepath.endsWith || !filepath.split) {
        return true;
    }
```

Where filepath is a String.

I wonder if that is valid usage and what might be the purpose of it?
I cannot find any documentation about calling String.endsWith() or String.split() without parentheses.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: did you try logging to console and see what it is? should be the first thing to do when trying to find out something. (this bit is just checking if the subject has both methods.)

Comment: either somebody forgot a `typeof filepath === "string"` in the equation, or that's some sort of feature detection that rules out every browser that doesn't support `endsWith`

Comment: I had some suspicions, that it is a kind of "collision protection", but was not sure, so wanted to ask :) Thanks!
@AndreaGiammarchi I agree that the type of give variable should be verified also.

Comment: I'd guess that it's *not always* a string, and this an attempt at duck typing (would be cleaner and clearer with `typeof filepath.endsWith != "function"`)